# ASP.NET MVC: Default page works, but other pages return 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a "Hello World" application, in the same vein as http://giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=409.  It works perfectly on my development computer, using the built-in web server.

I followed Phil Haack's advice for doing a Bin Deployment at http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx.  I used the Publish feature to get an output directory, and copied all of the files to the correct places on the ISP (Network Solutions).

When I go to the site, I get the welcome page, but when I do http://mydomain/hello, I get a 404 error.

What could be the problem?

---

Here is the fix.  Apparently Network Solutions is running IIS6 after all.  I got what I needed from http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/.  The new routing is

```
{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}
```

Notice the addition of the .aspx after the controller placeholder.  IIS6 needs this because it always thinks it is talking to an actual web page instead of a controller.

I'm not keen on the extra characters in the url, but I may have to live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you deployed it to an IIS7 server? If the server runs IIS6 check [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) and [this post](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/).

Comment: I'm inclined to go with [what's his name] on this one Robert.  I've only ever seen this when deploying to IIS6.  Or, and I'm assuming p=409 stands for page=409 from a db, that your connection to the database is not working for whatever reason.

Comment: What was it and should i create an answer? :)

Comment: So, the ISP was actually running IIS6?

Comment: Apparently...Could be my fault.  I may have assumed IIS7 since they have the bleeding edge .NET framework.  Bad assumption on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Another long shot: Do you know if your host has ASP.NET MVC installed in the server? If he doesn't, you need to [copy the three MVC DLLs to your BIN folder](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) as well.

Comment: And no, they don't have it installed, but that's another story :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but this very honestly happened to me today. Are you sure you have IIS configured completely? Under the Web Service Extensions node, enable/allow ASP.NET. If this isn't allowed, you'll get a 404 error.

Comment: It's the ISP's web server.  I have zero control, but good guess, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I had troubling 404 errors until I copied over 'PrecompiledApp.config'